# how validate the primefaces date

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this XHTML code. In this code, the Javascript validation doesnt run:

```
<h:form id="form1"  >

          <h:outputText  for="activity_start_date" value="start date: " /> 
              <p:calendar id="activity_start_date"  navigator="true" mindate="01/01/1950" yearRange="c-50:c+10" value="#{loginBean.activity_start_date}"  onblur="checkdate(this)" widgetVar="from"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" required="true" immediate="true" requiredMessage="Enter start date" />  
              <h:message for="activity_start_date" style="color:red"/>


              <h:outputText for="activity_end_date" value="end date: " /> 
              <p:calendar id="activity_end_date"    navigator="true" mindate="01/01/1950" yearRange="c-50:c+10" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" onblur="checkdate(this)" widgetVar="to"
              value="#{loginBean.activity_end_date}" required="true" immediate="true" requiredMessage="Enter end date"  />  
              <h:message for="activity_end_date" style="color:red"/>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function CompareDates()
{

var str1 = document.getElementById("form1\:activity_start_date").value;
var str2 = document.getElementById("form1\:activity_end_date").value;
alert("hai");
var dt1  = parseInt(str1.substring(0,2),10);
var mon1 = parseInt(str1.substring(3,5),10);
var yr1  = parseInt(str1.substring(6,10),10);
var dt2  = parseInt(str2.substring(0,2),10);
var mon2 = parseInt(str2.substring(3,5),10);
var yr2  = parseInt(str2.substring(6,10),10);
var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1, dt1);
var date2 = new Date(yr2, mon2, dt2);
if(date2 > date1)
{
    alert("To date cannot be greater than from date");
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert("Submitting ...");
    document.form1.submit();
  }
 }
</script>
```

I am using *primefaces3.0+jsf*. When I press the submit button it goes to the script section, but it doesn't execute body of script. Could you please give me a solution?

Comment: You should not edit an old question in to something *completely different*. It would make all answers invalid and confusing. Just ask a **new** question whenever you have a new question. I've rolled back your original question. Press the `Ask Question` button on the right top.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have much more luck and end up with cleaner code if you use the built in JSF validation functions:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnatn.html#bnatr

In this case you're validating fields against each other, the following link explains how to do this in jsf very well:

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html